# SQL database, Login failed for user ''

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I am currently trying to create a database for a website I am creating and have been following a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh2JCSUjA_E&ab_channel=CodingwithKevin).

I keep getting an error message that says "Error executing query: Login failed for user ' ' "

My server appears to be running correctly, I created a test file to test the connection and the connection was successful. My server is in Mixed mode and everything else appears to be fine. I was hoping someone could help me out, here is my code:

dbConfig.js

```
const config = {
    name: 'ArtPortfolio',
    password: 'kierrarg',
    server: 'DESKTOP-DC3RG3A',
    database: 'Contact',
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        enableArithAbort: true,
    },
    port: 1433
}

module.exports = config;
```

dbOperation.js

```
const config = require('./dbConfig'),
sql = require('mssql');

const getContact = async() => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let contact = pool.request().query("SELECT * from Contact")
        console.log(contact);
        return contact;
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log('Error executing query:', error.message);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getContact
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
dbOperation = require('./dbfiles/dbOperation'),
cors = require('cors');

const API_PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log('called');
    res.send({result: 'hellloooo'})
})

app.get('/quit', function(req, res) {
    console.log('called');
    res.send({result: 'byeeeeee'})
})

dbOperation.getContact().then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${API_PORT}`));
```

The tutorial also had me add these lines to my package.json file

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",


"server": "nodemon server.js",
```

Comment: you tagged w/ `mysql` but are using `mssql` in code. What are you actually using?

Comment: assuming `mssql`, should be `user:  ArtPortfoliio`, not `name: ArtPortfolio`

Comment: apologies I am using mssql and it worked thank you so much!